# Can I convert a list to a length indexed vector with a class?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

To avoid ragged matrices, I want to design a type wrapper for lists that holds length in type. *(Please correct me if I should not call it a "length-indexed vector".)* I would like to provide it as an abstract type with smart constructors, among which would be an [`IsList`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.10.1.0/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList) instance or something similar in spirit.

This is where I am:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Vector (n :: Nat) a = Vector [a] deriving Show

v0 :: Vector Z a
v0 = Vector [ ]

put :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a
put x (Vector xs) = Vector (x:xs)

class Fold a where
    type Elem a
    fold :: [Elem a] -> a

instance Fold (Vector Z a) where
    type Elem (Vector Z a) = a
    fold [ ] = v0

instance Fold (Vector (S n) a) where
    type Elem (Vector (S n) a) = a
    fold (x:xs) = put x (fold xs)
```

The `Fold` typeclass is supposed to take elements from a list one by one and `put` them to the vector. The instances I intend to represent the base case and the inductive case for structural induction along the `Nat`urals.

However, the code I posted does not work, and I cannot sort the errors out. In essence, it talks about the element types of vectors of different length not being equal:

```
...
  Expected type: [Elem (Vector n a)]
    Actual type: [Elem (Vector ('S n) a)]
...
     fold (x:xs) = put x (fold xs)
                               ^^
```

If I assume the magical coercion function:

```
    fold (x:xs) = put x (fold $ undefined xs)
```

− I will then reach another error:

```
    • No instance for (Fold (Vector n a)) arising from a use of ‘fold’
...
     fold (x:xs) = put x (fold $ undefined xs)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This saddens me because it must mean my inductive instance does not iterate.

I need help with this.

- Can I obtain an `IsList` instance this way?
- Can I obtain it at all?
- The point of dependent typing does not seem to get through to me. Do I think in the right direction at all? How can I tell what is doable with dependent types and what is not, so that I can judge the tractability of this particular case, and other cases that I may face in the future, by myself?

Comment: You just have to make the induction explicit: `instance Fold (Vector (S n) a) where` should be `instance Fold (Vector n a) => Fold (Vector (S n) a) where`

Comment: I totally missed the actual juice of your question. Rereading it, I realize that you were actually asking more about `IsList` than anything else. Please comment if you feel the answer to the question I marked this as a duplicate of doesn't address your question.

Comment: @Alec I was specifically interested in the possibility of approaching the `IsList` functionality as much as possible *without* resorting to "advanced" techniques such as singletons. There is a gap in my understanding that I want to bridge, rather than jump over: I must first see classical techniques reach their edge, in order to appreciate the cunning modern inventions. Before I opened this question, I had found several similar questions on Stack Overflow, but they all appeal to singletons, and that I specifically wanted to not get into yet.

Comment: Reopened. The point of the duplicates was just to say that what you want is fundamentally impossible in today's Haskell. The closest you can get is either with something where you specify the expected output length (but risk a runtime error if the list isn't long enough), or where you have an existential wrapper over the length type variable.

Comment: @Alec I find this link very useful. I see it's pinned in the right bar now; that is good.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is informing you of two different problems.

> In essence, it talks about the element types of vectors of different length not being equal:

Spot on! You have two approaches here. If you want to keep the `Elem` family as part of the typeclass, you'll have to add an extra constraint to the inductive case basically telling GHC "my element types are equal":

```
instance (Elem (Vector n a) ~ a) => Fold (Vector (S n) a) where
    type Elem (Vector (S n) a) = a
    fold (x:xs) = put x (fold xs)
```

Alternately, you could make that type family completely separate and have only one (more sensible) instance:

```
type family Elem xs :: *
type instance Elem (Vector n x) = x

class Fold a where
  fold :: [Elem a] -> a
```

Up to you!

> This saddens me because it must mean my inductive instance does not iterate.

Sure it doesn't "iterate", because you haven't told GHC to go find a recursive subproblem! Just add that subproblem to your constraint for the inductive case.

```
-- If you decided to keep the type family associated
instance (Elem (Vector n a) ~ a, Fold (Vector n a)) => Fold (Vector (S n) a) where
  type Elem (Vector (S n) a) = a
  fold (x:xs) = put x (fold xs)
```

or

```
-- If you decided not to keep the type family associated
instance Fold (Vector n a) => Fold (Vector (S n) a) where
  fold (x:xs) = put x (fold xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I obtain [an `IsList` instance] at all?

No. `IsList a` implies a function `[Elem a] -> a`. This is impossible for length-indexed vectors, because the signature demands the ouput type not depend on the input length. The closest you can get is the following:

```
data VecSomeLen a = forall (n :: Nat). VecSomeLen (Vector n a)
instance IsList (VecSomeLen a) where ...
-- and also
instance IsList (Maybe (Vector n a)) where ...
```

It’s not entirely useless, because it lifts a list with no size into one with unknown but manipulatable size/checks whether a list has a given length, but it’s pretty useless when you consider it’s usually used when the size is known.

I’d just use varargs.

```
-- untested but *should* compile
class MkVector n a n' r | r -> n a n' where
  mkVector :: (Vector n a -> Vector n' a) -> r
instance MkVector Z a n (Vector n a) where
  mkVector f = f $ Vector []
instance (MkVector n a n' r) => MkVector (S n) a n' (a -> r) where
  mkVector f x = mkVector $ \(Vector xs) -> f $ Vector $ x:xs

vector :: MkVector n a n r => r
vector = mkVector id

-- vector 1 5 3 :: Vector (S(S(S(Z)))) Int
```

Now, the thing is that your `Fold` class, though it can compile with @Alec’s change, is totally the wrong thing to do. Look at the type of the function you’ll create:

```
fold :: forall n. [a] -> Vector n a
```

That’s no good! Given a list of elements, you can make a sized list, except the new size is not related in any way to the input list. You seem to be getting around that with non-totality, which is just a terrible idea. Furthermore, if anyone comes by and tries to make `fold` total, it’s easy to break the `Vector` invariants by accident. Honestly, your definiton of `Vector` is somewhat odd. It’s easy to break its invariants because the backing data is not as strongly typed as its interface. I’d redefine it:

```
data Vector (n :: Nat) a where
  (:%:) :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a
  VNil  :: Vector Z a
infixr 5 :%:
-- infixr 5 :
```

Which makes it impossible to write a total `fold` (and that’s good, because its existence is a bug). However, you can no longer (safely) coerce to a normal list because this is no longer a newtype (but I believe they have the same representation anyway and can still be `unsafeCoerce`'d).

A better idea would be to encode the partiality with `Maybe`. Additionally, you can abstract out a certain pattern from the `Fold` class to make writing similar functions easier.

```
-- can’t match on types so match on SNat representatives
data SNat (n :: Nat) where
  SZ :: SNat Z
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat (S n)
-- pass SNats around implicitly
class KNat (n :: Nat) where kNat :: SNat n
instance KNat Z where kNat = SZ
instance KNat n => KNat (S n) = SS kNat
fromList' :: SNat n -> [a] -> Maybe (Vector n a)
fromList' (SS n) (x:xs) = (x :%:) <$> fromList' n xs
fromList' SZ [] = return VNil
fromList' _ _ = Nothing
fromList :: KNat n => [a] -> Maybe (Vector n a)
fromList = fromList' kNat
```

Comment: You are wrong in the final part. `fold` works with your definition of `Vector`, if I just redefine: `put = (:%:)` and `v0 = VNil`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a *total* function.